# "Import-Module MSMQ" fails on PowerShell @ Windows 11 Home/Pro

Tags: windows, powershell, msmq, system-administration

I had a script creating MSMQ queues on Windows 10 and everything worked fine. On Windows 11 however (Pro and Home, to be specific), it fails.

It started to fail by just not finding `New-MsmqQueue`:

```
The term 'New-MsmqQueue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program.
```

I tried to `Import-Module MSMQ` and it **almost** (almost, as we know, makes a huge difference) addressed a problem.

I say almost as `Import-Module MSMQ` also fails with:

```
The module manifest cannot contain both the 'ModuleToProcess' and 'RootModule' members. 
Change the module manifest file to remove one of these members at
'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSMQ\MSMQ.psd1', 
and then try again.
```

I looked inside the mentioned file and yes, in fact, it contains both `ModuleToProcess` and `RootModule` but first of all I should not edit system file and secondly... I cannot edit them.

I created a copy of this module and "experimentally" modified it (by removing `RootModule`) and it seems to be working fine, but this is not a solution.

**NOTE**: I'm running this on "fresh" installation (`Win11_22H2_EnglishInternational_x64v2.iso`)

**NOTE**: I tried both (Windows) PowerShell 5 and the new (Core) PowerShell 7.

**NOTE**: MsMQ Windows Feature is fully installed (all boxes ticked)

Anyone seen this? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: Windows 10 does not have this problem and does not have `RootModule` is `.psd1` file. As `RootModule` references `MSMQ.psm1` I checked it and it seems be dealing with Intel/ARM differences, and I assume it was not a case in Windows 10.

Comment: `set-executionpolicy unrestricted`

Comment: @js2010 definitely not this

Comment: Another option is `unblock-file`.

Comment: @js2010 what file you think requires unblocking and why?

Comment: It looks like Microsoft broke the module with a broken manifest. It seems like your only options are to wait for a fix or to create a manually patched copy that you must place in a directory that comes earlier in `$env:PSModulePath`. It looks like the module isn't open-sourced (at least I couldn't find it; the _documentation_ source is [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/tree/main/docset/winserver2022-ps/msmq)), so you'll have to use the Windows Feedback Hub application.